# Cannot upload new version of removed app on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-console

Our app has been removed from Play Store due to policy violation. We have removed all features related to SMS & Call from app and removed permissions from manifest file as well. Now we are unable to create a release on any of the tracks (alpha, beta or production) without selecting core functionality. Every time we try to create new release, it prompts to select any core functionality. But now we do not have any core functionality. Even if we select any 1 and publish, it's getting rejected. Please help how we can create a release without selecting any of the core functionality.

Comment: This sort of question is best asked to Google Play support, who you can contact through the help menu on the Play console

Comment: @NickFortescue Had already tried that as well. But wasn't getting any response and we were struggling from last 2 days, so as a last resort thought of asking here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay you have to delete all the previous version which have those permissions may be there in beta release,Delete these version and try releasing again.May this help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had  faced also same problems. Be sure to remove all your permissions which is violated by Google Play Console. Now you won't be able to add new release of same package name.Do again with starts.Now Change your project's package name to  new  package name.Create new Project on Google Console.Now you able to create new release either in Production,Alpha or Beta

I resolved it by doing this.Hope this will help you.Thanks